# Convert text in image file to text file

Tags: scanning, ocr

I have a PDF file which is a scan of a form containing pictures, tables and text.

I'd like to run a program (not an online tool) on the file and have it produce a txt file containing the words. Not too fussed about formatting.

Note that this is not a repeat of 'Convert pdf to text ignoring structure' as this refers to text in straight PDF documents, not scanned images stored as PDF.

Comment: Hi, i'm using acrobat 9 pro. Under menu Documents->OCR text recognition. Will this option help you? Because once you run a OCR - Adobe will allow you to select the text - copy and paste it into notepad (or word). Or there are tools to convert your PDF to word (post OCR run)... Will this automate your requirements?

Comment: @Prasanna, I need to run a program to do it, can Acrobat 9 be run non-interactively?

Comment: I've never used Acrobat 9 non-interactively, may be some one from the Adobe world can help? Conversely, can batch files open a program and navigate through menus as a person does - something like windows level macro.. Sorry i'm asking more questions than solving yours...

Comment: You basically need OCR.  If you have a scanner, some (primitive) OCR software may have been supplied with it.